# Finding directories which do not share history with the current tip

Tags: mercurial

I have a repos which I'm about to split in two (using `hg convert`). I'd like to take the opportunity to get rid of (`exclude`) unnecessary directories. However, in some cases, I moved files around using `hg cp` and so forth, so seemingly unused directories may have old history assocated with them, and in some cases I have verified they do. (In most cases this is very old history (from around 2004/2005). I do this much less now). Is there a way I can check a particular directory does not share history with the current tip? By this I mean that for a directory `foo`:

```
hg log -vf filename
```

for all `filename` in tip does not mention any files in `foo`.

I think that is a sufficient criteria.

EDIT: I belatedly realized that the above question is wrong. In my case most of these original directories are still in tip, so what I said above won't work. Instead, say DIR_1, DIR_2, ..., DIR_k is directories which are currently (in tip) no longer relevant. I want to make sure they never were relevant. In other words, consider all files not in any of DIR_1, DIR_2, ..., DIR_k. Then check that their ancestors doesn't include a changeset in any of these DIR. If it does, then I guess you need to exclude that directory from the list of non-relevant directories, and try again.

EDIT2: Ok, let's break this down a bit. Can someone tell me what the expression for the set of all csets which touch files in a specific directory `DIR` is? The following seems close, but I'm not sure how to interpret the expression `**.*`.

```
hg log -vr "file('c++/**.*')"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled on the following script.

Brief description: The basic idea is to find directories which aren't part of the history of the files in the tip. So, this script takes all files in the tip and removes those from the chosen set of directories. Then it does `hg log -vf` for each of those files, and checks whether any of the files in that log match the files in that set of directories. If they don't, then those directories can be safely deleted.

I am sure this script could be improved - my shell scripting is quite dodgy. Suggestions for improvement appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh

hg locate "set:not lisp/** and not boost/** and not trunk/** and not 'c_api_ex/**' and not 'c++-strategy/**' and not parallel/** and not poster/** and not sim/**" > file.txt

while read f; do
    filelist=$(hg log -vf $f --template "{files % ' {file}\n'}")
    one_file_per_line=""
    for file in $filelist
    do
    one_file_per_line="${one_file_per_line}""\n""${file}"
    done
    filematches=$(echo -e $one_file_per_line | sort -u | egrep 'lisp/|boost/|trunk/|c_api_ex/|c++-strategy/|parallel/|poster/|sim/')
    if [ -n "${filematches}" ]; then
        echo file $f has the following files as ancestors in one or more of lisp, boost, trunk, c_api_ex, c++-strategy, parallel, poster, sim directories: $filematches
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try for directory DIR such revset

`hg log -r "ancestors(tip) and file('DIR/**.*')"`

Any output means "Found in history"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a followup and as a check (should have asked this as part fo the question) given a hit for some file in DIR, is it possible to trace what file in tip is a descendant of that file? So then one can do `hg log -vf file_in_tip` and see the file in DIR. Actually, I just tried this on a directory which I'm pretty sure shares no history with tip, and I got all the directory history from the command above, which looks wrong.

Comment: Sorry, just realised that that my comment about is nonsense. The problem is that the `DIR` is still in tip, so of course it will return non-zero results. I guess the question should be - does DIR share history with anything outside DIR?

Comment: @FaheemMitha - try this: `hg log "set:DIR/**.*" --template "{files % '  {file}\n'}" | sort -u` and handwork on results. If it will fail: `hg locate "set:DIR/**.*" -0 | xargs hg log -f --template "{files % '  {file}\n'}"` and pipe this output over `dirname` (I'm lost with one more xargs here)

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, but I'm not seeing what you are shooting for here. Can you elaborate? Specifically, what is the first command supposed to return, and what does "handwork on results" mean? Perhaps you could just put it in your answer? Also, according to Matt Mackall (who should know), one should use `DIR/**` instead of `DIR/**.*` to match anything. To quote him, "This will not match files without extensions."

Comment: @FaheemMitha - log with set must (I think) return `hg log FILENAME` for every file in DIR and output only list of files (EOL-separated)... and I forgot `-f` here. Sort with -u will sort these filenames (with path prepended to filename), you have to check only dir-part of files. Second form do the same thing, but not for all files in single log, but for "one file per one log". Matt is right about pattern, mea culpa

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at this more carefully. Can you provide a reference for the `set:` syntax? I don't see it in `hg help revsets`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - it's **not** revsets. `hg help filesets` + `hg help patterns`

Comment: Oh, I see. I had forgotten the existence of `filesets`. Thanks for the tip.